# WPF ListView store item condition

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

For example i have ListView, item chang `FontWeight` when double click event was raised. How to save the state to the next start of the program? Use database? What it be better to store in database string variable something like Bold,ExtraBold,Normal. Or values?

What is common way to store state

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="itemstyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#FFF0F0F0">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" Margin="0,0,0,62" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemstyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="SecondName">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <CheckBox Content="HideAllNormal" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication27
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ListViewModel LVM = new ListViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = LVM;
        }

        protected void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            LVM.SelectedEmployee.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LVM.HideAllBold();
        }

        private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LVM.ShowAll();
        }
    }

    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Employee> items;

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return items;
            }

            set
            {
                items = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("Items");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Employee> WithBoldItems;

        public Employee SelectedEmployee { get; set; }

        public ListViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.Number = i;
                emp.FirstName = "Test";
                emp.FontWeight = (FontWeight)new FontWeightConverter().ConvertFromString("Bold");
                Items.Add(emp);
            }
        }

        public void HideAllBold()
        {
            WithBoldItems = Items;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(Items.Where(key => key.FontWeight != FontWeights.Bold));
        }

        public void ShowAll()
        {
            Items = WithBoldItems;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

    }

    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        private FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

        public FontWeight FontWeight
        {
            get
            {
                return fontWeight;
            }

            set
            {
                fontWeight = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("FontWeight");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have saved the state in the main Application check this hope it helps.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);

            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        #if DEBUG
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Installed location: {Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path}");

                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
                    }

    #endif




        RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (RootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            RootFrame = new Frame();

            RootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            Debug.WriteLine(e.PreviousExecutionState);


            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated || e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser)
            {

                await xxxxx.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();



            }


            if (true)
            {
                try
                {
                        await xxxx(await Utils.DeserializeXML<xxx>(
                        await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("xxx.xml")));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No in xxx");
                }
            }



            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = RootFrame;
            await AssetManager.InitAssets();
            // Place the frame in the current Window


            await AssetManager.FetchAssets();

        }

        if (RootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter

            if (App.xxxx == null || App.xxxx.SessionId == null)
                RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(xxxPage), e.Arguments);
            else
                RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();





    }


    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("xxxxxx " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }


    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        // it would be best to have a SUSPEND state in the statechart for every possible
        // state, but it's ok for now
        Utils.ReleaseDisplay();

        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

        try {
            if (App.LoggedUser != null)
            {
                await Utils.SerializeXML(await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "xxx.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting), xxxxx);
                await Utils.SerializeXML(await App.xxxFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "xxx.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting), App.State);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e2);
        }

        await xxxxx.Common.SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();
        deferral.Complete();
    }

}
```